# K-means clustering with proc fastclus (SAS) maintaining observations ordered

Tags: sas, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have to cluster my population in `8 clusters`. I'm using `proc fastclus` and the `k-means` method (to minimize the variance between the clusters). Observations represent a score, so it's important that even after the clustering process, they remain ordered. I noticed that in this way:

```
proc sort data=input.population; 
by score; 
run;

proc fastclus data = input.population 
              maxclusters = 8 list 
              out = score_clus 
              converge = 0.01 maxiter = 100 
              least = 2 noprint; 
var score; 
run;
```

the procedure didn't maintain the order. There is a way (maybe a parameter of the proc) that I can use to put another bond: minimize the variance, but maintain the score ordered inside the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could make a note of the row order before you run the proc and then sort within each cluster afterwards? If you want to use this as a clustering dimension, standardise it and feed it as one of the inputs to the proc.

E.g. why not create a view with an extra variable like this?

```
data input.v_population / view = input.v_population;
set input.population;
myorder + 1;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on user667489's answer.  Add an ID or `SORT_ORDER` variable to the data.  Then just sort that at the end.

```
data cars / view=cars;
set sashelp.cars;
SORT_ORDER +1;
run;

proc fastclus data = cars 
              maxclusters = 8 list 
              out = score_clus 
              converge = 0.01 maxiter = 100 
              least = 2 noprint; 
var msrp; 
run;

proc sort data=score_clus;
by SORT_ORDER;
run;
```

This creates a view with the `SORT_ORDER` variable, then runs `PROC FASCLUS` on the data in the view, and then sorts the results as you want.